# Timing a sourced bash script

Tags: bash, time

Normally I simply call the `time` program when I want to profile a script or a command it runs.

But this time (no pun intended), I want to measure the time it takes to execute a sourced script, such as:

```
/usr/bin/time source myscript.sh
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run source: No such file or directory
```

And sourcing it this way:

```
/usr/bin/time . myscript.sh
```

Simply gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run .: Permission denied
```

I can call it in the following two ways:

```
/usr/bin/time ./myscript.sh
/usr/bin/time bash myscript.sh
```

But it's really important that I source my script.  Anyone know how I can do this?

---

**Additional Context**:

We have many, many scripts which are somewhat complex and these scripts know how to source a specific 'set' of other 'client' scripts.  We'll call these scripts 'bundles'.

```
bundle-a.sh
bundle-b.sh
...
bundle-z.sh
```

That's not exactly how they are named, but it serves the purpose of showing 26 of them in this example. Each bundle contain a lot of logic and each bundle invoke a specific set of client scripts.

There are hundreds of client scripts, some with a few lines of code and others that are really complex and take hours to execute.

```
client-000.sh
client-001.sh
...
client-300.sh
```

We also provide a script which serves as an API library for both our bundle scripts and our client scripts.  Many, many functions in this API.

```
api.sh
```

So the bundle scripts source the API library and so does each client script.  We have it this way so that a bundle can be called (which call a set of client scripts) or at times we only need to call a specific client script directly. It is implemented in a way that if the bundle is executed, the API library is only sourced once (and not again from the client script).

So all of this has worked well for a long time.  Its just that now I'm trying to add the /usr/bin/time to each sourcing of our client scripts from the bundle scripts.

Comment: Why is sourcing important if all you're doing is profiling?

Comment: Because I need to profile the execution of various scripts but need to run them sourced from our existing scripts.  It's passive profiling, meaning that I redirect the time output into all the logs that the main script generates.  This can be used for later analysis.

Comment: Instead of using the external utility `time`, use the shell-keyword `time`.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but essentially our main script provides a ton of reusable functions (our API) and is quite large.  The scripts I'm sourcing comes from clients and they use our script API we provide them.  Their scripts can take minutes or sometimes hours.

Comment: @devnull I'm not sure what the difference is but if I use simply 'time' I can't use any options (ie: -o -f), but if I use /usr/bin/time, then I can use '-f' flag and capture memory, I/O, context switches, user/sys time, signals, etc.

Comment: @Jeach It would help to understand what are you trying to achieve by sourcing the script.

Comment: @devnull I will try to add more context to my question, but it's a little complicated.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, *really* need to get the system and user times of a sourced script, you can use `strace` from  a different shell to watch the one you're timing in, trace calls to `getrusage`, and inspect the return values.

Shell 1 (where you will time the script)

```
$ echo $$
12345
```

Shell 2 (where you will trace)

```
$ strace -etrace=getrusage -v -p 12345
Process 12345 attached - interrupt to quit
```

Shell 1:

```
$ time : ; . myscript.sh ; time :
real 0m0.000s  
(( time output and script output, then time output again)
```

Shell 2:  will output something like

```
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 12000}, ru_stime={0, 16001}, ru_maxrss=2364, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=1551, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=1032, ru_nivcsw=3}) = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 4000}, ru_maxrss=1216, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=5143, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=57, ru_nivcsw=21}) = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 448028}, ru_stime={0, 16001}, ru_maxrss=2364, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=1552, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=2141, ru_nivcsw=22}) = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 4000}, ru_maxrss=1216, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=5143, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=57, ru_nivcsw=21}) = 0
```

Notice how the values in the `ru_utime` structure element changed?  The difference there is how much user CPU time the shell itself used.  See `man getrusage` for the details on exactly what you are seeing.  From there, it's just a automatically extracting those and finding the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly just the lack of a `./` in your reference to `myscript.sh` *(which I note you use in your working examples, but not elsewhere)*

---

Have tested under Ubuntu (Trusty64), and Darwnin/BSD - just using the following works fine:

```
time source ./myscript.sh
```

---

FWIW, I used the following script to just confirm that the `source` command was actually executing correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

V_FIRST=1
export V_SECOND=2
```

*Execution under darwin:*

```
$ time source ./test.sh ; set | grep -i V_

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
RBENV_SHELL=bash
V_FIRST=1
V_SECOND=2
```

*Execution under Ubuntu:*

```
$ time source ./test.sh ; set | grep -i V_

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
V_FIRST=1
V_SECOND=2
```